# Determine when Legend is ready

Tags: events, svg, highcharts, legend, ready

I am looking to place a text element (or two) below the legend, aligned with it's right side, but I can't get consistent coordinates.

Warning: I am a relative noob at SVG.

I have a series of datasets that I want to show charts for.  As I move from one to the other, I'm adding new serieses and deleting old ones.  After each update, I attempt to place a string, which include the dataset's average, below the legend.  The problem I am running into is that **every other** time that I query the x & y attributes, the string ends up outside of the chart.  The other half of the time, I get a perfect result.

The code I'm using to place this string is:

```
var tbl=table[3];
$('.usData').remove();

//get legend x & y
startX =  chart.legend.group.translateX;
endX = startX + chart.legend.legendWidth;
startY = chart.legend.group.translateY;
endY = startY + chart.legend.legendHeight;
$(tbl.usAvg).each(function(i){
chart.renderer.text("National Avg: " + formatData(this,tbl.format), endX, endY+(i*15)+15).attr({'text-anchor':'end',zIndex:12, class:'usData'}).add();
```

What I think is happening is that the legend starts outside of the plot and is translated into it's position.  Therefore, I am unable to reliably "grab" accurate coordinates until it is done rendering.

**So, my question:**  Is there a way to determine (event) when the legend is finished moving, or do I simply have to include a timeout and wait?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest simpler solution, with setting useHTML for legend. http://jsfiddle.net/aWFYr/1/

```
$('#btn').click(function(){

        $('.highcharts-legend').append('<div style="position:absolute;top:'+(chart.legend.legendHeight)+'px">aaa</div>');

    });
```

Comment: Yes, but then the added div is not present in the exported image/pdf.  That is part of the end objective.

Comment: Is not displayed in exported image, because it is dynamic content, but when you export chart then it is created again. You can try to add this instrucion in load event: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load